# MONGODB Full Text Search Logical OR Query

Tags: mongodb, indexing, full-text-search, nosql

I am currently working on a project where a large database (+25.000.000 records) needs to be searched (on a local machine) in under the 1000ms. That made me think of MongoDB and the desired performance can be reached. I can do this by several different kinds of indexes, however I need to be able to match partially.

The end user is allowed to search on a couple of fields. (**Not all of the fields; Need to be able to search 5/9 of the fields the rest is meta data not searchable for the end user**)

I first tried creating a compound index (on all 5 of the fields) for full text search

`db.tracks.find({$text:{$search:"Greatest Hits"}})`

This seems to be working rather well and giving me all sorts of results with Great, Greatest and Hits on any of the compound fields.

However a user should be able to select the fields that he wants to search on. (For example: AlbumTitle, TrackTitle etc). This means that When track title is toggled off I don't want results from that column.

```
db.tracks.find({AlbumTitle: "Greatest Hits"})
```

The above query would be able to find exact matches and thus not finding the same result when searching on Greatest. This made me think of something like the following

```
db.tracks.find({AlbumTitle: {$text: {$search: "Greatest Hits"}}})
```

but that doesn't work because then $text would be an unknown operator.

If something like the above would be possible I would be able to build my query dynamically based on the toggled fields like

```
db.tracks.find({$or: [ {ToggledField1: ...}, {ToggeldField4: ...}  ]})
```

and thus ensuring only the needed fields are queried. Would this at all be possible inside a MongoDB database, and if so what is the best way to achieve the desired functionality

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I can hear a voice telling me [regex](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Comment: Would this not be to time consuming? Since the database needs to be searched in less then 1000 ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved it as listed below

```cs
// Create an empty filter and make sure it is not null
var builder = Builders<Track>.Filter;
FilterDefinition<Track> filter = builder.Empty;

string[] searchWords = queryString.Split(' ');
if (ArtistChecked){
  foreach (var words in searchWords){
   //regex could be changed with options like ignore case
   filter &= builder.Regex("Artist", BsonRegularExpression.Create(new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(word)));
  }
}
if (AlbumChecked){
  foreach (var words in searchWords){
   //regex could be changed with options like ignore case
   filter &= builder.Regex("Album", BsonRegularExpression.Create(new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(word)));
  }
}
```

In the end you use the build filter in your MongoQuery; it is possible to mix in OR-Operators and use EQ for some fields in the query; but this way you could dynamically build the query.
Off course the performance is not as good as on exact matches (with using the FullTextSearch) but this would make the search method needed available. Performance could be beter by using index and saying it starts with prefix

> If an index exists for the field, then MongoDB matches the regular expression against the values in the index, which can be faster than a collection scan. Further optimization can occur if the regular expression is a “prefix expression”, which means that all potential matches start with the same string. This allows MongoDB to construct a “range” from that prefix and only match against those values from the index that fall within that range.

source: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use

In my case this won't do because user should be able to enter search words in any order they want; and since it just has to appear inside of the field there is no way to guarantee that the correct order is used.

Open for suggestions how to make this faster/better

P.S. Got the idea to solve it from [MongoDB substring product search order by highest match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677234/mongodb-substring-product-search-order-by-highest-match)